How to communicate from one LWC to another LWC component
I am having two LWC components(A and B) and there is relation between these components. A LWC component is in lightning tab and displaying in flexi page(lighnting page). B LWC component is add community site LWR page. from A component need to pass the value to B component. i have tried Lightning Message service but it is not working. can anybody help me to achieve this.
